# Sequential IDs with field calculator: Pad a prefixed field to specific length

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, field-calculator, python-parser, unique-id

I have an ID field that is a text datatype. The IDs in the field have a prefix, and are padded with zeros to always be a specific length. Examples:

- INSP000098
- INSP000099
- INSP000100
- INSP000101

I would like to use the Field Calculator to generate sequential IDs for new records (records are [batch loaded](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/loading-data-in-arccatalog.htm) from various sources by the thousands).

**I have a python script that *almost* does this:**

Modified from: [Create sequential numbers in a field using Python in the Field Calculator](http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011137)

```
prefix = "INSP0000"
lastnumber=97

rec=0
def autoIncrement(): 
 global rec 
 pStart = 1  
 pInterval = 1 
 if (rec == 0):  
  rec = 1 + lastnumber
 else:  
  rec += pInterval 
 return prefix+str(rec)
```

---

```
autoIncrement()
```

**Steps:**

1. Manually enter the prefix (with zeros for padding)
2. Manually enter the last number in the existing IDs
3. Run the script

**Result:**

Unfortunately, the tool isn't smart enough to dynamically adjust for the difference in the number of digits between numbers (99 to 100, etc.):

- INSP000098
- INSP000099
- INSP0000100  << Problem: too many zeros/digits
- INSP0000101

**How can I use the field calculator to generate sequential, prefixed IDs that are padded with zeros to a specific length?**

I'm not married to Python; VBScript would be an acceptable alternative.

Comment: 'Insp%s' %str(autoincrement()).zfill(6)

Comment: Do you want the 100 and 101 value to be INSP000100 and INSP000101?

Comment: Type this instead of autoincrement. Use standard example of autoincrement from help system

Comment: I have a similar question here: [Field Calculator: Prefixed, padded IDs from a number field](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254462/field-calculator-prefixed-padded-ids-from-a-number-field/254463#254463)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rec=97
def withPads():
 global rec
 rec+=1
 return 'INSP%s' %str(rec).zfill(6)
#------------
withPads()
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: That's pretty slick.

Comment: Feel free to post your own answer, do not amend my one please, because calculator is a pain to work with sometimes. I prefer to keep it short

Comment: Ok. I don't know how to cancel my edit. But I will post my own as requested. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slight twist on FelixIP's answer. It's a bit more user friendly for non-python people.

The user edits the variables at the top, rather than trying to interpret and edit the code body.

```
prefix="INSP"
numlength=6
lastnumber=97

rec=lastnumber
def seqID():
 global rec
 rec+=1
 return prefix+'%s' %str(rec).zfill(numlength)

#------------

seqID()
```

Answer (score 1):

Add some if logic at the end to evaluate the rec number length, try:

```
prefix = "INSP0000"
lastnumber=97
rec=0
def autoIncrement():
 global rec
 pStart = 1
 pInterval = 1
 if (rec == 0):
  rec = 1 + lastnumber
 else:
  rec += pInterval
 if len(str(rec)) == 2:
  return "INSP0000" + str(rec)
 elif len(str(rec)) == 3:
  return "INSP000" + str(rec)
 elif len(str(rec)) == 4:
  return "INSP00" + str(rec)
 else:
  return 'add more elif conditions'
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to do this dynamically, without hard coding in multiple IF statements?

Comment: That may be hard to do within the field calculator since there is no way to get the total feature count before iterating through all features to help dynamically figure out the max rec length.  I would recommend using arcpy for this (get count and update cursor).