# Field Calculator: Prefixed, padded IDs from a number field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, field-calculator, python-parser, unique-id

Using the Field Calculator, I want to create prefixed, padded IDs from an existing number field. By "padded", I mean I want the IDs to have a specific number of characters, regardless of how many digits the numbers have.

For example, I want to use the values in `OBJECTID` to create IDs like:

- `OBJECTID` `8` >>> `INSP000008`
- `OBJECTID` `9`  >>> `INSP000009`
- `OBJECTID` `10` >> `INSP000010`
- `OBJECTID` `11` >> `INSP000011`

Note: All the resulting IDs have the same number of characters (10).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the logic from my [Sequential IDs script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252913/sequential-ids-with-field-calculator-pad-a-prefixed-field-to-specific-length). I changed it to use the values in an existing number field, rather than generating sequential IDs.

It seems to do the trick:

```
prefix="INSP"
numlength=6

def IDfromNumberField(num):
    return prefix+'%s' %str(num).zfill(numlength)

__esri_field_calculator_splitter__
IDfromNumberField( !YourExistingNumberFieldHere! )
```